# Are there alternatives to using the Node Access module?

Tags: users

I have installed the [Node Access](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module in a site, in order to assign view/edit capabilities to specific roles.

1. The pages in which I have granted "edit" permissions to specific roles show the editing option to users of that role, which is good; however, pages that have been limited to be viewed by only role X, and role Y are still viewable to any logged in user, wether they are in role X and Y or not. Has anyone experience this? All settings have been checked out, and there are no conflicting modules.
2. Is there a better module that has the same features the Node Access module implements?

Comment: Did you rebuild node permissions from the status report page?

Comment: you can try "Content Access"                       http://drupal.org/project/content_access

Comment: @MPD, I rebuild the permissions, but still edit only works. Nothing is correctly blocked.

Comment: @Sathiya I looked at that, however on first glance, it seems to order it by node type. Then I saw it does pretty much the same as this one. I will try it out. Thank you